# Calculate gradient inside numpy mask

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate the gradient inside a mask. I was hoping that I could use the gradient function on the mask. However, it not only fails to do that, it even changes the mask.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([[1,4,2],[6,2,4],[-1,5,1]])
>>> masked_a=np.ma.masked_where(a<0,a)
>>> masked_a.mask
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> v,u=np.gradient(masked_a)
>>> masked_a.mask
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool
```

Does anyone know how to apply the gradient function inside the mask?

Comment: executing your code my output is:
    `masked_a.mask`

    `array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)`

Comment: Cannot reproduce your data; get the same as @FrancescoNazzaro.

Comment: try to update numpy. `pip install --upgrade numpy`